# AWS S3 cp failing to go through

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to run a recursive copy command using AWS s3 cp CLI. The command I'm running is below (I replaced the real bucket name with "mybucket"):

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ /home/bob/work/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include “monthly_summary_*” --region us-east-1
```

I'm also going to format it so that it fits:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ /home/bob/work/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ 
--recursive --exclude "*" --include “monthly_summary_*” --region us-east-1
```

For some reason, this is failing to work. However, it doesn't log any errors or output of any kind. Is there a syntactical error?

I have verified that the file matching the "monthly_summary_*" does exist in the bucket at that location. I have also verified that I can do a normal aws s3 cp command without --recursive, --exclude, and --include and just specifying a file name and it will work. Meaning, the below code works but does not get everything (since it's not recursive):

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/monthly_summary_201406.txt
/home/bob/work/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/monthly_summary_201406.txt --region us-east-1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try running this command: `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ /home/bob/work/NJ/Monthly/2014/06/ 
--recursive --exclude "*" --include "monthly_summary_*" --region us-east-1`

Comment: Isn't this the same command that I'm running above?

Comment: No - the include parameter was using smart quotes, and I changes them to dumb quotes. Does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. It appears the AWS command line tools do not support wild cards fully, they only support them as far as file extensions. So "*.txt" will work with the --exclude "*" --include "*.txt" logic, but wildcards such as "monthly_*_summary.txt" or "monthly_summary_*" will not work.

Comment: Wow really? you would think the AWS docs would mention that. Their examples only show extensions but they don't specify that. Also its weird because S3 is not actualy files but objects, and the path is just a 'label". Anyway glad you figured it out - now I'll know to avoid trying that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old. But wanted to update. The command now works even when `monthly_summary_*` is used!

Answer (score 1):

In case this is useful for anyone else coming after me: Add some extra spaces between the source and target. I been beating my head against running a similar command with every combination of single quotes, double quotes, slashes, etc:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/ s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv"
```

And it would give me: "aws: error: too few arguments" Every. Single. Way. I. Tried.

So finally saw the --debug option in `aws s3 cp help`
so ran it again this way:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/ s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv" --debug
```

And this was the relevant debug line:

```
MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['s3', 'cp', 'home/<username>/folder\xc2\xa0s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/', '--recursive', '--exclude', '*', '--include', '*.csv', '--debug']
```

I have no idea where `\xc2\xa0` came from in between source and target, but there it is! Updated the line to add a couple extra spaces and now it runs without errors:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/   s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

**--recursive**, add that to the end of the cp command.

The AWS doc says:

> The following example copies all objects from s3://bucket-name/example
> to s3://my-bucket/.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/example s3://my-bucket/
```

But it did nothing for me.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/example s3://my-bucket/ --recursive
```

Worked fine.